# Trouble filtering null JSON data with Criteria in Shopware 6

Tags: shopware6

How to Null check for JSON field with Criteria?

I'm trying to add a filter on the orders page in the admin panel to see if customers have tax numbers. But the field where tax numbers are kept is of json type. I add filter of type existence-filter with `listFilterOptions` function.

```php
options['vat-id-filter'] = {
    property         : 'orderCustomer.customer.vatIds',
    type             : 'existence-filter',
    label            : this.$tc('sw-order-list.filters.vat-id.placeholder'),
    optionHasCriteria: this.$tc('sw-order-list.filters.vat-id.textHasCriteria'),
    optionNoCriteria : this.$tc('sw-order-list.filters.vat-id.textNoCriteria'),
};
```

It filters non-null data, but I cannot filter null data. Because in order to convert it to SQL, it is caught in the `ListField` control in the `parseEqualsFilter` function in the `SqlQueryParser` class and surrounded by `JSON_CONTAINS`.

Example

```php
WHERE (`order`.`version_id` = ?) AND ((JSON_CONTAINS(`order.orderCustomer.customer`.`vat_ids`, JSON_ARRAY(?))))
```

Do I have to write decorator for this process? Is there any other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is kind of an odd case. And in this case I would honestly suggest [creating a ticket](https://issues.shopware.com/) on the issue tracker, asking for support of `null` checks on `ListField` types. Either that or providing a solution as described below.

While you could technically decorate services of the database abstraction layer, it is highly discouraged. Almost all of those classes are marked `@internal` for that exact reason. These classes are not exempt from breaking changes during the minor release cycles and it will probably cause frustration when things break then.

You could create your own administration controller for custom admin api endpoints, inject `Doctrine\DBAL\Connection` and use it to fetch the ids of those records with `null` values, to then include them in criteria with the database abstraction layer. However this may not be great in terms of performance and you'd have to integrate use of the new endpoints within the administration.

The fastest way to get this done, would be to [create a pull request](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/resources/guidelines/code/contribution) on the GitHub repository. It's a tiny change, but you might have to provide tests as well to cover the change.

Changing [this line](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/dc23169c8fc7d9dfe38ac3ca7684e988978992ed/src/Core/Framework/DataAbstractionLayer/Search/Parser/SqlQueryParser.php#L237) should do the trick with pretty much no negative side effects or breaking changes. Maybe additional tests would not even be necessary. I suggest you try your luck with a pull request.

```php
private function parseEqualsFilter(EqualsFilter $query, EntityDefinition $definition, string $root, Context $context, bool $negated): ParseResult
{
    // ...
    if ($field instanceof ListField && $query->getValue() !== null) {
        // ...
    }
    
    // ...
```